# Android mobile number verification process

Tags: android, verification, phone-number

I need help from you all in Android mobile number verification process. I have an application, Where the user enters his mobile number. I need to verify that the user has entered  his own mobile number and not someone else mobile number in that application. How can i achieve that. Any ideas will be of great help. I am very much confused in how to verify the user input.

looking forward for your replies.

Thanks

Comment: i've pointed out the solution for this on

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370980/mobile-number-verification-android/28198065#28198065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer would be very easy. You can try the same logic of Mobile Banking Process. See the Steps,

- Register Number via web site.
- Now Send a random number to that Entered Mobile Number.
- Now comes verification point, create a page that accept the random number sent as sms on that particular Mobile.
- If both random number are same then that is valid mobile number, else not.

Comment: Is there any other way except this(Sending tokens). Verify mobile number entered with mobile MSISDN number. App doesnt have website online registeration. Any other options

Comment: Simple Answer "NO", when you are taking Mobile Number input the SMS would be the most easiest way. However, you can ask user's email and do same verification process on email.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to send a SMS to that number. And ask for a transmitted token.

Comment: Is there any other way except this(Sending tokens). Verify mobile number entered with mobile MSISDN number.

Answer (score 0):

Another way economic way for the platform would be to send a simple SMS from the mobile to the same MSISDN with a random token. If the device receives the token the verification will succeed, otherwise it won't.

When I meant "*economic*" it is because the customer incurs the expenses of the SMS and not our platform. Thus, we avoid to pay attention to massive or distributed registration attacks and the cost of all those SMS's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending sms from user's mobile phone to himself and send a code and also save this code in preferences. Ask user to input this code into your application then compare that code with the one that you saved in preferences earlier (original). if both matches, then mobile number varified.