# Mobile number verification android

Tags: android, mobile-application

I want to integrate mobile number verification in my Android application by sending an SMS from the user's mobile, so is there any API which allows verification of a mobile number by sending an SMS, apart from sending an SMS to a user's mobile?

Comment: I am curious what did you end up using. I am dealing with this issue now and need to make a choice

Answer (score 6):

i recommend [cognalys](https://www.cognalys.com) for [android](https://www.cognalys.com/androidlibrary/)

the demo app is available on [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matesnetwork.cogdemo)

and its source code on [github](https://github.com/cognalys/cogdemo)

this will be helpful to verify mobile number internationally

Because its a new way of verifying mobile number without fee . SMS method is a traditional method.

Comment: The reviews on their play store app leave much to be desired

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go for Digits Api provided by fabric platform, Below is the link for the documentation.It is free of cost and also very authentic.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html

Comment: yes, but not suggested if you want to show your own UI. Digit won't let you customize whole UI, but some color scheme.