# Mobile Number Verification during registration by message from api like that in “viber” or whatsapp for android

Tags: android, mobile, messaging

I am making a messaging application and we need to verify the user mobile number by sending short code through SMS from users mobile(user will be charged for outgoing SMS ).

We are able to send sms and even able to verify but the message is going from user's name so how to change this user's name to custom name as it is done in whatsapp or other application.

DW-Whatsapp
AM-Telegram

Please advice.

Comment: You can't change outgoing sms.Those app use sms gateways.

Comment: you can find the solution on 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370980/mobile-number-verification-android/28198065#28198065