# Communication using mobile number as an identifier

Tags: android

I am developing an app which communicates between mobiles using phone number as an identifier. Very similar to the way Whatsapp does. The problem is different countries use different mobile number formats and also how people save them as contacts in their phone.

For e.g. a person may save a number as 6122323345 in one country but could be saved as (country code)6122323345 in another country or (exit code)(country code)6122323345 in a different country. Also not to mention the different number of mobile digits followed by different countries which makes looking up the country code kind of very difficult.

Just wanted to know if there is an API or algorithm available to manage this at both client and server side. Or any code to help in this situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android mobile number verification process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511217/android-mobile-number-verification-process)

Comment: no I did not ask for mobile number verification. I am doing that currently in my app

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

what about using only the last, say, ten digits of the phone number as the identifier? In this way it won't matter if there are any country codes or other signs at the beginning. Of course you can get collisions, but you will be a millionaire before seeing the first one :)

Comment: this was my thought initially but some countries have 7 or 8 digits only in their mobile numbers in which case the collision will be more.

Comment: you might use the country taken from the locale settings to take care of collisions.